# How to convert $\min x^{1.5}$ into a SOCP problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I want to optimize: $\min x^{1.5}$ (with some other constraints and variables, but they are not related to this question) using Second Order Cone Programming. Therefore, I wonder how I can do it? Thanks for any suggestions!

I have tried `cvx` and it automagically converted it to a SOCP successfully <sub>(and solved using ECOS)</sub>. I have tried to read it's source code, but cannot understand it. To my best understanding (not sure if correct or not), it transforms the question to form the weighted geometric mean: $t \leq x^{\frac{2}{3}}  1^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Then it's `gm_constrs` functions' transforms it automagically into some Second Order Constraints of the following parameters (I do not know what  var0~var3 is):

```
first constraint: t=var2+var3, X=[var2-var3, 2 * var0]
second constraint: t=1+var0, X=[1-var0, 2 * var3]
```

Where SOC is defined as

````
class SOC(Constraint):
    """A second-order cone constraint for each row/column.

    Assumes ``t`` is a vector the same length as ``X``'s columns (rows) for
    ``axis == 0`` (``1``).

    Attributes:
        t: The scalar part of the second-order constraint.
        X: A matrix whose rows/columns are each a cone.
        axis: Slice by column 0 or row 1.
...
```
````

Comment: It is shown in release 2.3 (but not current) version of the Mosek Modeling Cookbook, section 3.2.9, which can be downloaded at https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-v2.pdf . That section was removed from rreleases 3.x, because its need, from a Mosek user's viewpoint, was eliminated by the introduction of power cones in Mosek

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone could you please make it an answer such that I can accept it

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I have made the derivation (see the answer)

Comment: It is still mentioned in passing in the current cookbook by the way https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#simple-sets-involving-power-functions

Answer (score 1):

With hints given [in the comments of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302275/how-to-convert-min-x1-5-into-a-socp-problem?noredirect=1#comment8960930_4302275), and by looking at source code of `cvxpy` (look at `Dcp2Cone`'s `cone_canon_methods`'s `power_canon`), I make the derivation as follows:

$$
v \ge u^{3/2}, u \ge 0
\\ \Leftrightarrow
u \le v^{2/3} 1^{1/3}
\ \text{(power_canon func)}
\\ \Leftrightarrow
u \le v^{1/2} 1^{1/4} u^{1/4}
\ \text{(gm_constrs :: dyad_completion; and cookbook)}
\\ \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
v w \ge u^2 \\
1 u \ge w^2 \\
\end{cases}
\ \text{(look at gm_constrs output; and cookbook)}
\\ \text{where w is a new variable}
\\ \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
gm(u,v,w) \\
gm(w,1,u) \\
\end{cases}
$$